# Calculate integral inequation

Tags: integration, inequality

$I_n$ = $\int_{2}^{3} \frac{x^ndx}{x^2-1}$, $n$$\in$$N$.

Show that

$I_n$ $ \le$ $\frac{3^n}{2}$$ln{\frac{3}2{}}$

I manage to find out this difference:

$I_{n+2}$ - $I_n$ = $\frac{3^{n+1} - 2^{n+1}}{n+1}$, $\forall n \in N $

But I can not solve that inequation for $I_n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Rather than solving some difference equation, it's actually much easier to use the inequality
$$I_n=\int_2^3 \frac{x^n}{x^2-1}~dx\leq \int_2^3 \frac{3^n}{x^2-1}~dx,$$
and to write $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$ and use partial fractions.